# iOS change BackgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a simple checkbox in a tableview. First I create the View in the storyboard and every element get a tag in the cell. Then I coded this in Controller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    UIButton  *checkbox = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    checkbox.selected = NO;

    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
}

-(void) changeState:(UIButton *)checkbox
{

    checkbox.selected = !checkbox.selected;
    if (checkbox.selected)
        [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    else
       [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

But if I tap on the button the image don't change. Why is this and how I fix it?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This is because everytime calling *cellForRowAtIndexPath:*  `checkbox.selected = NO;` will make the selected property **FALSE**. So after that, in the  **changeState:**,

```
checkbox.selected = !checkbox.selected;
```

will change the selected property to **TRUE**. So whenever you tap the button, selected property becomes **TRUE** only. So move **checkbox.selected = NO;** to inside of `if(cell == nil)` condition

Answer (score 1):

Make it like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    UIButton  *checkbox = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:103];

    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
}

-(void) changeState:(UIButton *)checkbox
{

    checkbox.selected = !checkbox.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code you have given in your button tap event is not needed. Only changing the state is enough.

```
    if (checkbox.selected)
        [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    else
       [checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uCheckbox2px"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But you need to specify the image for both states (`UIControlStateSelected` and `UIControlStateNormal`) in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.